# Error Listening for Data message while connecting telegraf with influx database

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, influxdb-2, telegraf-plugins

I am trying to connect telegraf with influx database for system monitoring. Have configured API token and started started telegraf as per the instructions given in the influx database. But when clicking on "Listen for data" it's showing "Error listening for Data".

Attaching the screen shots of the terminal and database interface also.

[Influx db screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbwwM.png)

[Terminal screenshot showing connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzhJU.png)

Comment: Would be best to look at the telegraf logs and see if it is actually sending metrics or if you are encountering any errors or issues.